# How to install GIT on an offline Ubuntu 7.10?

Tags: ubuntu, git

I'm using the following commands from the [manual](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) to install GIT

```
$ tar -zxf git-1.7.2.2.tar.gz
$ cd git-1.7.2.2
$ make prefix=/usr/local all
$ sudo make prefix=/usr/local install
```

but I'm receiving the following exceptions

```
...
cache.h: At top level:
cache.h:746: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âtime_tâ
cache.h:889: warning: âstruct timevalâ declared inside parameter list
cache.h:895: warning: âstruct timevalâ declared inside parameter list
cache.h:970: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âoff_tâ
cache.h:979: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âoff_tâ
cache.h:997: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âoff_tâ
cache.h:1057: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âoff_tâ
cache.h:1063: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âuint32_tâ
cache.h:1064: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before ânt                                                                                                                     h_packed_object_offsetâ
cache.h:1065: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âfi                                                                                                                     nd_pack_entry_oneâ
cache.h:1067: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âoff_tâ
cache.h:1069: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âoff_tâ
cache.h:1070: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âoff_tâ
cache.h:1094: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âoff_tâ
cache.h:1168: error: expected â)â before â*â token
cache.h:1177: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âre                                                                                                                     ad_in_fullâ
cache.h:1178: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âwr                                                                                                                     ite_in_fullâ
cache.h:1179: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âwr                                                                                                                     ite_str_in_fullâ
cache.h:1252: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âFILEâ
In file included from credential-store.c:2:
credential.h:28: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âFILEâ
credential.h:29: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âFILEâ
In file included from credential-store.c:4:
parse-options.h:115: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âintptr_tâ
credential-store.c: In function âparse_credential_fileâ:
credential-store.c:13: error: âFILEâ undeclared (first use in this function)
credential-store.c:13: error: âfhâ undeclared (first use in this function)
credential-store.c:17: warning: implicit declaration of function âfopenâ
credential-store.c:19: error: âerrnoâ undeclared (first use in this function)
credential-store.c:19: error: âENOENTâ undeclared (first use in this function)
credential-store.c:24: error: too many arguments to function âstrbuf_getlineâ
credential-store.c:24: error: âEOFâ undeclared (first use in this function)
credential-store.c:39: warning: implicit declaration of function âfcloseâ
credential-store.c: In function âprint_entryâ:
credential-store.c:44: warning: implicit declaration of function âprintfâ
credential-store.c:44: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in fu                                                                                                                     nction âprintfâ
credential-store.c: In function âmainâ:
credential-store.c:132: warning: implicit declaration of function âumaskâ
credential-store.c:144: error: âstdinâ undeclared (first use in this function)
credential-store.c:144: error: too many arguments to function âcredential_readâ
credential-store.c:147: warning: implicit declaration of function âstrcmpâ
```

Is this because I didn't install the dependencies?

```
apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev gettext libz-dev libssl-dev
```

How do I install them offline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install git offline you could type `sudo apt-get install git` and copy the urls of the packages apt-get tries to download. Then you can download them on another PC and install the downloaded .deb-files manually either with gdebi or, if not installed, by typing `dpkg -i packagename.deb`.

Note that you have to install the packages in the right order to assure that every dependency is installed before the package depending on it.